# get translateX to use viewport width rather that element width

Tags: css, animation

I was using CSS left for an animation and I'm moving over to translateX for performance reasons. Then I stumbled upon the following:

Two divs:

```
<div class="box box1">Using CSS left:20%;</div>
<div class="box box2">Using CSS transform: translateX(20%);</div>
```

and some CSS:

```
.box {
    width:500px;
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    position: relative;
}

.box1 {
    left:20%;
}

.box2 {
    transform: translateX(20%);
}
```

Produces this:

[image]

Turns out that `translateX` uses the element width while `left` uses with viewport/parent element width.

How do I make translateX use the viewport/parent width?

http://jsfiddle.net/Vd2nK/

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
.box2 {
    transform: translateX(20vw);
}
```

which, combined with

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

gives the same result as `left: 20%;`. Note, thought, that the `vw` unit (which equals 1/100th of the width of the viewport) requires a fairly modern browser.

Here's a fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vd2nK/6/